# Play different audioplayers in sequence Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

So basically I have two audio players while using the AVFoundation. I want the second one to be played right after the first one finishes.

```
myFilePathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(workout[currentExercise])", ofType: "mp3")
@IBAction func startWorkout(sender: AnyObject) {                
    if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString {            
        let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)            
        do {               
           try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)

            audioPlayer.play()

        }catch {
            print("Error")
        }            
    }
```

This above one is to be the first

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Rest", ofType: "mp3")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        secondAudioPlayer = sound
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```

...while this one is to be played after. At the moment they play at the same time. Got any ideas for me?

Thank you in advance.